# Two Variable Function - $f(x,y)=x^2y+1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was given the following two-variable function:
$$f(x,y)=x^2y+1$$

I have to evaluate the function at the following point $f(ab,a-b)$.

I began the problem by direct substitution, which resulted in the following:

\begin{align}
f(ab,a-b)&=(ab)^2(a-b)+1 \\ &= a^2b^2(a-b)+1 \\ &=a^3b^2-a^2b^3+1
\end{align}

My question is that if my procedure is right as well as if these problems types typically involve a simple direct substitution for multi-variable functions?

Comment: Yes, your result is correct. Calculating $f(ab,a-b)$ only is a simple substitution in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are answer is correct. Let me give you another example:
\begin{align*}
f(a+3,3) &= (a+3)^2(3) + 1 \\
f(a+3,3) &= 3(a^2+6a+9) + 1 = 3a^2 + 18a + 27 + 1 \\
f(a+3,3) &=  3a^2 + 18a + 28
\end{align*}

I hope this helps.